# how to get current time of specific timezone using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any method or function in PHP which can get the current DateTime of specific timezone from internet. Not the time of local system. please Guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/Paris'));
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Replace `'Europe/Paris'` with whatever timezone you want

Comment: @HamzaHafeez your question sounds like you wanted the date coming from the internet (an API), to avoid issues with wrong local time.
If that's what you want, I believe DateTime and DateTimezone won't help, as they calculate starting from your system's date/time.

Comment: @Mark Baker Can you tel me how to get timezone of local system in php?

Comment: Local system where? The web browser? The server?

Comment: The web browser @MarkBaker

Comment: using date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris') then echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s T') would do it? depends on your usage though? can get the 'local server time' by omitting the date_default_timezone_set(). You cannot get the local time of the client computer using PHP as its a server-side language, you would need to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: You'd need to get the webbrowser to send that information to the server

Comment: @MarkBaker your answer marked as correct